# Not able to access @IBInspectable property from framework

Tags: frameworks, swift4.2

I am packaging the extension that I use day to day in my workflow. 
I am extracting this Extension on UIView and putting it into a framework.

I did initial build and all these IBInspectable properties are not accessible in the project where this framework is being used. 
Below is the code of the UIView's extension that is in the separate framwork.

```
public extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }

        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.borderWidth
        }

        set {
            self.layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let borderColor =  self.layer.borderColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: borderColor)
        }

        set {
            self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let shadowColor =  self.layer.shadowColor else {
                return nil
            }
            return UIColor(cgColor: shadowColor)
        }

        set {
            self.layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return self.layer.shadowOffset
        }

        set {
            self.layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.shadowRadius
        }

        set {
            self.layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: CGFloat {
        get {
            return CGFloat(self.layer.shadowOpacity)
        }

        set {
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on, What I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use open instead of public as access specifier to access class and Variable out side the module.

```
open extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable open var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }

        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }
```